# How to make this imageview appear on the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

First, I am adding Gridview and second i add imageview in the gridview, but the layout can't show up the image。

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thank you very much!!

[image: the Imageview couldn't appear]

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the **height** and **width** attributes :)

Comment: Do you mean Layout_height and Layout_width?thanks for your reply!!

Comment: still not working :(  but thank!(I change it to (height)100dp、(width)100dp)

Comment: can you include your xml too?

Comment: Final, i change different version of android studio, and it work

Answer (score 0):

Don't drag, use xml text editor instead. And as mentioned above use height and width appropriate.

Comment: Even use xml text edit , It's not working,but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio shows you a warning, next to the ImageView (yellow warning icon). If you hover over this, it will tell you what the problem is. (most likely missing height and width)

Comment: It said missing content Description XD